# AVSpeechSynthesizer Detect end of speaking?

Tags: ios, avspeechsynthesizer

I want to be able to tell when the speech synthesizer has finished speaking its utterance. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at setting a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate) for your synthesizer?